# Step by Step App Debugger Checksum?

Tags: unit-testing, debugging, testing, compiler-construction, state

From the standpoint of a debugger, there is a global state, which sums up the entire global context of an applications run state.

This state, I assume, could be assessed or accumulated into in a single file, which itself could be summarized as single checksum, at any point in time.

Therefore, a debugger based step by step global checksum could be used to easily find where a program differs from where it used to operate, in comparison to where it currently operates, given of course the exact same inputs.

**Does this exist in any development environment, or as a library/RFC that could be used cross language?**

In my particular case, I'm porting an app from VB6 to C#, and am constantly walking the code in both environments to find where my port is broken. It seems to me that if there were some library that existed that could, in debug mode, store the above detailed checksum, on a step by step basis, then I could easily find where my port was broken without having to step through line by line by line.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Instead of focusing on one specific (possible?) implementation, consider focusing on the task. Let X start as X.

Comment: That's what I'm doing. But in this particular scenario, I've got thousands of lines of code that have been automatically ported using a tool. It seems like ~85% of the code is a spot on port, but that last 15% is costing me time. And time, when your a consultant with schedules, is money. I want to get it working exactly the same as it used to, then I'm going to improve it via refactoring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me like you'd need to have a per language implementation of this library that wrote data out in a consistent format.

for example, in C#, you might have data in a List
in javascript, you might have it in an array.

These 2 structures are different, and couldn't be written out the same way without a lib managing this process.

Is it doable? I think so. But I don't know of any library to do so. Interesting idea!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a solid foundation of unit tests instead.
It seems a lot more brittle and difficult to try to serialize the "state" of your application into a "check sum". You can serialize the state of the classes that make up your app, but again, to me this doesn't sound like the best approach.

Comment: well in reality it's not meant to be a unit test, per se, but a simple way, with the same inputs to find out where something has changed, on inputs vs outputs. I described it that way, because, how else would you describe it in 10 words or less ;-) Thanks for the feedback!